# Automatic mapping domains to folders in Homestead

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Homestead configuration file, `Homestead.yaml`, offers way to map domains to folders, like this:

```
sites:
    - map: project.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/www/project.dev/public
    - map: some-other.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/www/some-other.dev/public
    # etc.
```

Is there any way to automate this process and map all .dev domains to the folders, like this?

```
/home/vagrant/www/{domain}/public
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old thread but you can do this

`sites:
    - map: '~^(?<project>.+)\.dev$'
      to: /home/vagrant/Development/\$project/public`

Comment: I figured it out ages ago, but didn't update this topic. You deserve the points :)

Comment: I didn't understand, my sites have to start with "projects"? Can you point out some documentation so I can understand what's happening in there?

Comment: @LucasBustamante
 No, your sites don't have to start with projects
project is a placeholder variable that will contain the url

so `lucas.dev` will map to `/home/Vagrant/development/lucas/public`
and `bustamante.dev` will map to `/home/Vagrant/development/bustamante/public`